# can't access to a global variable in event handler method (javascript)

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, eventhandler

I wanna know why i can't access (guessNumber) variable in Event handler method  which is declared out of this function... this number gets from input field but console.log returns me 0 each time

```js
let showScore = document.querySelector('.score');
const guessNumber = Number(document.querySelector('.guess').value);
const secret = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
let score = 20;

checkBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(guessNumber);
  if (!guessNumber) {
    message.textContent = 'No Number!';
    console.log(guessNumber);
  }
```

Comment: The value of `guessNumber` simply is 0!? Why would you expect any different value?

Comment: Are you trying to change the value inside `.guess`? And expect to see that value in your handler?

Comment: @TusharShahi when I declare GuessNumber in the handler function everything is alright. I just did not know why when the declaration of this value is out of the handler function not working truly

Comment: Because the GuessNumber value never changes. Remember your script is run only once, your handler runs multiple times. If value is defined outside, it never changes and remains 0.

Comment: Add more information on what are you trying to achieve ? and if there are problems. since the above code block does not exhibit a useful functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the value of `guessNumber` doesn't exist at the time the listener is added to the button.

Cache the element first, and *then* access the value when you click the button.

```js
const message = document.querySelector('div');
const checkBtn = document.querySelector('button');
const showScore = document.querySelector('.score');
const input = document.querySelector('.guess');
const secret = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
let score = 20;

checkBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const guessNumber = input.value;
  if (!guessNumber) {
    message.textContent = 'No Number!';
  } else {
    console.log(guessNumber);
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="guess" />
<button>Click</button>
<div />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have access to this variable because if you don't, console.log will print "undefined" but its current value is 0.
check the console.log output, out of event handler block.